# Use of unresolved identifier NSWorkspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I would like to open a url in browser but I get this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier NSWorkspace

my code:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"), NSWorkspace.shared().open(url) {
    print("default browser was successfully opened")
}
```

Comment: make sure you `import Cocoa`

Comment: To want import Cocoa I got this error: `No such module Cocoa`

Comment: I have a MacBook pro and my OS is X EI Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: @Leo Dabus's answer work fine.

Comment: @AhmadF shared is a property not a method in iOS

Comment: When working with iOS, `NSWorkspace.shared()` should be `UIApplication.shared`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a code for macOS coding for iOS. When coding for iOS you have to use `UIApplication.shared`

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) { 
    UIApplication.shared.open(url) 
}
```